# Workbox registerRoute issues with Firebase Storage CORS

Tags: javascript, firebase, caching, service-worker, workbox

I'm facing some issues trying to use Workbox's `registerRoute` function to pre-cache images from Firebase Storage. I already enabled the CORS configuration via Google Shell to the Bucket I'm using and changed the CacheFirst `fetchOptions` property to include the "cors" mode for the requests but I'm still getting a lot of CORS errors.

My `cors.json`:

```json
[
    {
        "origin": [
            "*"
        ],
        "method": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "responseHeader": [
            "Content-Type"
        ],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

My `registerRoute` configuration:

```js
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';
import { CacheFirst } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';

const setup = () => {
  registerRoute(
    new RegExp('https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.*'),
    new CacheFirst({
      cacheName: 'images',
      fetchOptions: {
        mode: 'cors',
      },
      plugins: [
        new CacheableResponsePlugin({
          statuses: [200],
        }),
        new ExpirationPlugin({
          maxEntries: 2000, // number of images to cache
          maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
        }),
      ],
    }),
    'GET',
  );
};

export { setup };
```

What am I doing wrong?